# Correlated state-space models

Tags: arma, state-space-models

I'm struggling with Reinsel's book "Elements of Multivariate Time Series Analysis," because I thought that it would be a good idea to switch from Vector ARMA to state-space representations; particularly after reading [What are disadvantages of state-space models and Kalman Filter for time-series modelling?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78287/what-are-disadvantages-of-state-space-models-and-kalman-filter-for-time-series-m), and after struggling with parameter estimation of VARMA processes.

The problem is that I can't see how correlation between two time series can be modeled in state-space representations. Is it that the correlation appears in the error covariance matrices? It sounds weird to me, particularly coming from VARMA. (Switching to state-space models is being harder than I thought!)

Answer (score 5):

Correlation can be introduced via the covariance matrices, but also through non zero off-diagonal terms in the transition or observation matrix.

Comment: About your kind answer: (1) if I introduce the correlation in the transition matrix (off-diagonal elements), isn't it that I'm forcing a deterministic correlation? I mean that it seems that I'm forcing say x1 and x2 to be always varying by the same amount. (If the off-diagonal matrix entry is 2, I am saying that x2 will "always" be double the value of x1.) (2) Do you know of any good resource where i can find how to estimate the state-space of two cross-correlated time series?

Comment: (1) no, because the total correlation will include the error covariance. (2) see my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93861/kalman-filter-and-box-cox/93862#93862)

Comment: @Sonntag, as pointed in the previous comment, if in one of your state equations you have x1(t+1) = a*x1(t) + b*x2(t) + eps(t), the connection between x1(t) and x2(t) is not deterministic, for it is affected by the state equation noise eps(t).